# Delphi Generics: E2037: Declaration of 'XXX' differs from previous declaration

Tags: c++, delphi, generics

I want to convert my C++ code to Delphi code. But I get this error from Delphi compiler: `Declaration of 'callFunction<T>' differs from previous declaration`.

**My C++ code:**

```
class Example
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  static void callFunction(const T value);
};

template<>
void Example::callFunction<int>(const int value)
{
  cout << "Integer = " << value << endl;
}

template<>
void Example::callFunction<double>(const double value)
{
  cout << "Double = " << value << endl;
}

template<>
void Example::callFunction<char*>(char* const value)
{
  cout << "Char* = " << value << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Example::callFunction<int>(17);
  Example::callFunction<double>(3.8);
  Example::callFunction<char*>("Hello");

  return 0;
}
```

This code is running succesfully. But my Object Pascal code is not running.

**My Delphi code:**

```
type
  Example = class
  public
    class procedure callFunction<T>(const val: T);
  end;

{ Example }

class procedure Example.callFunction<Integer>(const val: Integer);
begin
  Writeln('Integer');
end;

class procedure Example.callFunction<Double>(const val: Double);
begin
  Writeln('Double');
end;

class procedure Example.callFunction<PChar>(const val: PChar);
begin
  Writeln('PChar');
end;

begin
  Example.callFunction<Integer>(17);
  Example.callFunction<Double>(3.8);
  Example.callFunction<PChar>('Hello');

  Readln;
end.
```

How can I convert my C++ code to Delphi code? What is reason of the error? Can I convert my code to Delphi like this? Thanks.

Comment: Templates and generics are quite different. Delphi generics has nothing quite like C++ template specialization. This looks like an artificial problem, created for the purpose of asking the question. So you may need to make it more realistic in order to get good recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dsm explained, Delphi Generics do not support specialization like C++ Templates do.  However, all is not lost.  You *can* do the following with Generics (though it kind of defeats the purpose of using Generics):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  Example = class
  public
    class procedure callFunction<T>(const value: T);
  end;

class procedure Example.callFunction<T>(const value: T);
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then
    WriteLn('Integer = ', PInteger(@value)^)
  else
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Double) then
    WriteLn('Double = ', PDouble(@value)^)
  else
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(String) then
    WriteLn('String = ', PString(@value)^);
end;

begin
  Example.callFunction<Integer>(17);
  Example.callFunction<Double>(3.8);
  Example.callFunction<String>('Hello');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

> Integer = 17
>   Double =  3.80000000000000E+0000
>   String = Hello

Answer (score 5):

I think that you misunderstand generics. The whole point about generics is that you don't explicitly use the type within the class definition so lines like

```
class procedure Example.callFunction<Integer>(const val: Integer);
```

are not legal. Instead, in this case you would not use generics, but overloaded functions, like this.

```
type
  Example = class
  public
    class procedure callFunction(const val: integer); overload;
    class procedure callFunction(const val: double); overload; 
    class procedure callFunction(const val: string); overload;
  end;

{ Example }

class procedure Example.callFunction(const val: Integer);
begin
  Writeln('Integer');
end;

class procedure Example.callFunction(const val: Double);
begin
  Writeln('Double');
end;

class procedure Example.callFunction(const val: string);
begin
  Writeln('string');
end;

begin
  Example.callFunction(17);
  Example.callFunction(3.8);
  Example.callFunction('Hello');

  Readln;
end.
```

Note that I have used string rather than PChar, since this is more likely what you need.